# How Does this piece of code work

Tags: windows, contextmenu

```
@echo off
SET st3Path=C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe

rem add it for all file types
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%1\"" /f

rem add it for folders
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%1\"" /f
pause
```

Comment: how? I dunno, you mean what does it do?

Comment: its a batch file that uses reg.exe to add entries to the registry to create shell menu context entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It modifies Windows registry, adding registry keys that correspond to shell interactions (right click) on both folders and file types. It adds a menu item to open items in sublime text.

After running it, you can inspect the registry using `regedit`.

Details:

```
@echo off
```

The `@` causes the line not to be echoed to screen when it is executed. `echo off` does the same thing for the rest of the script.

```
SET st3Path=C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe
```

Sets an environment variable.

```
rem add it for all file types
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%1\"" /f
```

This block uses the `reg` command to alter the registry. The `@` modifier is used although it is not necessary because an `echo off` command was issued earlier.

The `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` corresponds to the right click menu options for all file types. It adds an option to open with Sublime Text. The three registry keys correspond to the same definition: the first line defines the option, the second one the icon, the third one the command to execute: here `\"%%1\"` is stored as `"%1"`, which is ultimately replaced by the path to the selected file when executed by the explorer.

You can check `reg` syntax using `reg add /?` on your command line. The different options specify the data type of the key (`/t`), the key name (`/v`), the actual data content (`/d`), overwrite existing keys (`/f`).

The data structure for *file name extension associations* is described by Microsoft here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475(v=vs.85).aspx

```
rem add it for folders
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%1\"" /f
pause
```

This does the equivalent for folders.